how could be calculating combinations with rule is bigger than the all possibilities?
I'm trying solve a math question but i stuck on something,
Lets say you have $30$ boxes, and you have to put one letter each box. You can put A,B or C for each box. Total combination for this is $3^{30}$ because you can put any letter to any box.
$3^{30} = 205,891,132,094,649$
on the other hand, lets say you have to put $3$ (A) letters together and other $27$ boxes could be any letter. What is the combination for that?
when I try to calculate I found this solution. $3$ (A) letter could be $28$ ways in $30$ boxes $(x-y+1)$ ( for example ..BCAAACB.., AAABBB..). And other boxes could be anything so that makes $3^{27}$.
Total combination for that $28*3^{27} = 213,516,729,579,636$
how my second calculation could be bigger then first calculation? Because my first calculation contains all posibilitys.

Once you have assigned the three $A-$boxes, you only have two letters left to use ($B,C$).  Thus there are $2^{27}$ ways to label the $27$ remaining boxes.

Or possibly I have not understood the rules.  Can there be other $A's$ besides the block of three?  What you wrote is not clear.  If you do allow other $A's$, then you have multiply counted the strings that have more than one $AAA$ block.

If my second reading is correct, then it is easier to count those strings with no $AAA$ blocks.  After all, and such string must start with one of  $X, AX, AAX$ where $X\in {B,C}$ so you can count those recursively.

there can be A besides the block of three @lulu

Then see my second two comments.

it can be found in other ways too. But i am try to understand why my calculation is wrong.

I told you.  If your string has two distinct blocks of $AAA$ then you count it (at least) twice.  After all, you have no way to tell which of those blocks was the one you put in first and which was the one that appeared "incidentally".

Try it for strings of length $4$.  There are two ways to put in an $AAA$ block initially.  $AAA*$ or $* AAA$.  According to you, that means there are $6$ such strings.  But there are only $5$ really...you are counting $AAAA$ twice.
